# HTML5 Validation of Checkbox Groups

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I <3 doing validation in the browser instead of using something framework specific. Using element.setCustomValidity you can change the message shown in the tooltip. It's perfect for every element, but I don't know how to handle a checkbox group.

Let's say you have three checkboxes, and you have to choose 2. The desired result is to have the tooltip surround the set, instructing the user to pick 2 before proceeding.

How does html5 allow this? That's what I am always scared of, the non typical uses cases and how you can make it all work in concert with the rest of the validation behavior which is awesome (focus first invalid field, tooltips, enter keypress submission).

Thoughts?

Here's a snippet example.

```html
<form>
Choose your favorite two stooges.
<label>Moe</label><input type="checkbox" name="stooges">
<label>Larry</label><input type="checkbox" name="stooges">
<label>Curley</label><input type="checkbox" name="stooges">
<label>Yes, I have agreed to this</label><input required name="ack">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post a small example form that requires validation. Preferably with 3 checkboxes that need validation *and* some other element which you are already validating. This may help us to answer more specifically. You can use either jsfiddle.net or the Snippet button on the StackOverflow question iself.

Comment: In theory (according to specs) you can wrap the group in a `<fieldset>` and call `setCustomValidity` on that, but in practice browsers don't support that very well, or at all...

Comment: I suspect that you will have to have some custom JavaScript. That is a sure-fire way to handle the *"non typical use cases*". I think that having an example form from you will help us give you something that *"works in concert"*.

Comment: So the desired result would be, if I fill in the required text field, and click submit, the tooltip is focused around the checkboxes, with the message to choose 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a function which iterates over all the checkboxes and return only true if 2 checkboxes are checked.

So the tooltip can show you 2 at the beginning and then 1 and if there are no checkboxes needed for continuation you can render the checkboxes green or if the user tries to continue without 2 checkboxes you can render the boxes red

Comment: Yes but how to show the tooltip around the checkbox group? The same tooltip that the browser uses to show an invalid field?